# What's an elegant way to handle an invalid form in a MVC application controller?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, design-patterns, frameworks

I have a custom MVC application/framework where each action is a function inside of a controller class.

I have a `signup` action which renders a view with a form requesting user details.  On submit it posts to a `processSignup` action that validates the data and either inserts the user into the database and redirects to a success page or needs to redisplay the original view/form with the errors.

The `signup` action runs several queries and hands off a variety of data to the view.  E.g. it needs to get a list of available countries that the user can choose in a drop-down, retrieve a list of suggested usernames based on the name they entered on a previous form, and retrieve other data from a model.

I'm trying to find out how I can avoid repeating all these queries and the render of the view in my `processSignup` action in the event of an error.  What's the standard way to handle these situations?  The `signup` action receives `POST` data from a previous form so I can't have the signup form submit to itself and branch based on `GET` vs `POST`.

I could just call the `signup` function directly and have it receive an optional parameter to differentiate between normal requests and ones for invalid forms but that seems hackish.  How do other frameworks handle this scenario?  I'm using PHP but this is more of a high-level question than one specific to the language.

Comment: Do you use any framework of only your own scripts? Usually frameworks like Zend of Symfony have excellent classes for processing forms, running data through validators and upon validation error will show the same form with error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoiding duplicate code certainly isn't unique to MVC frameworks. The standard approach would be to simply create a private function that both `signup` and `processSignup` call before rendering the view. Something like:

```
private function setCommonVars()
{
    // set country, username arrays, etc...

}
```

As far as rendering the `signup` view, the flexible thing about MVC is that you can reuse views. Your framework should have a way of explicitly choosing a view within a controller method (e.g., `$this->view = 'signup'`). That way, if an error occurs in `processSignup`, you can choose the `signup` view before rendering.